# VB.NET Data getting cleared from the modal popup on parent window post back

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

I have modal dialog with some text fields. In the parent window I have a repeater,  if I click on item_command of the repeater the data entered in the text fields of the modal dialog are cleared.Post back event clear the data in the dialog .All these are inside the same update panel. I have tried putting both in different update panel but didn't work.How can I solve this?

Comment: You are missing the code. Also, what is a 'repeater'? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Are you keeping one update panel inside another?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Repeater is an asp.net control

Comment: @PiyushKhanna No both are  different update panels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two different update panels for both repeater and modal dialog. Also put UpdateMode for dialog's update panel as Conditional and use AsyncPostBackTrigger for the same update panel
for eg.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate> 
.....Repeater Control goes here........
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
........other html goes here........
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>                       
<div id="divadvance" runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" Style="width: 85%;"></asp:TextBox>
<input type="button" runat="server" id="btSearch" />
</div>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btSearch" EventName="ServerClick" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```